# How to make a really high performance like factorio in SDL2?

Tags: sdl2

i tried to make a 2D game engine for my game, used SDL2 as framework, C++ as language, and MSVC as compiler, using the graphics api and accelarated renderer. However, this still not enough. The game, at 300 objects. (Object being a simple struct holding position and SDL_Texture, and also SDL_Rect) runs smoothly at 60FPS. While suddenly goes down to around 30 at 700 objects. Each object runs SDL_RenderCopy individually, using their pointer to the texture, and individual SDL_Rect for srcrect and another one for their position in the world. I've been searching for a while and couldn't find anything useful about sprite batching in SDL2. But I heard liballegro has this feature.

My goal is to reach the performance of Factorio, rendering a huge, animated tilemap, with thousands of objects(a.k.a items, or alliens). Hence this is why I chose C++ as the language. I've been using engine like Unity and GameMaker, the game i want to port is [here](https://hanprog.itch.io/afk).

I drew every objects in a for loop like this:

```
for (GameObject* obj : objects) {
        obj->render();
}
```

Is there even any kind of sprite batching in SDL2? Should I switch to Allegro? Or is there any better frameworks for my kind of problems and needs? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use one of the most latest versions of SDL, you'll actually have sprite batching for free. If the flag for disabling the sprite batching is not set, SDL will automatically batch the rendering for you.

Comment: Also, are you doing any frustum culling during the rendering of your objects? Frustum culling your objects, by checking if an object is visible by your conceptual camera and only render the objects visible, will drastically reduce the number of objects being rendered, which in turn can increase your performance.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply ^-^. I am using SDL2 and already enabled the batching flag. Though there is no performance change at all. Is there a really optimized way to render a thousands of sprites in SDL2? And also I will do frustum later on. Since the game itself id gonna have around 1000-2000 textures displayed on regular basis. And all will be dynamic. All of the world tilemap already baked into one big texture

Comment: What does your profiler tell you?

Comment: Hmmm. I think that wont help much. It just jumps high when I got to 700 objects and there's just pause for a few frames then suddenly drops to 30fps

Comment: A profiler will help immensely, as you can pinpoint the exact bottleneck.

Comment: shouldn't it only be rendering objects on the screen?

Comment: Exactly like Almo said, But I still can't figure out how to render so much sprites at the same  time without dropping the frames